# Set static method mock before instantiation in tests

Tags: php, phpunit

I have an abstract class that calls a static method in it's constructor. However, when writing a test in PHPUnit, when I try to create a mock for it, it complains because the static method is abstract, and thus not defined when constructed.

```php
$interface = $this->getMockForAbstractClass(ConnectionAdapterInterface::class, [[]]);
$interface->method('createConnection')
    ->willReturn(new TestConnection());
$connection = $interface::createConnection();
```

```php
abstract class ConnectionAdapterInterface
{

    public function __construct(array $configs) {
        $this->connection = static::createConnection($configs);
    }

    abstract public static function createConnection(array $config);

}
```

It gives the error `Static method "createConnection" cannot be invoked on mock object`.

Please ignore that the class is called interface; it's one in function but poorly named and I can't think of how else to name it.

Answer (score 2):

Static methods cannot be stubbed or mocked.

Comment: Oh... so then there's no way for me to test that method, is there? I tried making a test class that extended that abstract, but PHPUnit kept giving me errors.